# Cant find startup folder on 2 x Win10 machines

Tags: windows-10

I am having trouble with finding the startup folder, and I cant find an answer anywhere.
I have tried shell:startup    shell:common startup
Also startup is not there under %AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\

I have unhidden system folders

This is on 2 x Win10 machines.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Note, if you are seeking for a program that is being started automatically, there are more places where a program can start from. The registry is an option and a scheduled task is one. Also GPO, login script is one.

Comment: For that matter, use Microsoft/Sysinternals Autoruns, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns, to view *all* startup items, and to jump to the location.

Answer (score 2):

The main startup folder (shared by all users) is %ProgramData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp. The user-specific one is %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup. (Or, at least it is on the computers that I use both at home and at work. If it's missing, perhaps you could create it again.)

Comment: Don't know who voted down the answer, but I voted it up because it seems correct.

Comment: Correct, +1; in Explorer, copy/paste those strings into the location bar to view.

Answer (score 0):

The first bit 'All Users' worked. Thanks very much. That tripped me up. Everything else on the net said "%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup". This doesnt exist for me - perhaps because I dont have individual users setup on the PC.

Comment: AFAIK, every Windows 10 machine has at least one user set up, even if it's not set up with a password. (Check the C:\Users folder; the folders under there (other than Administrator, Default, Public, TEMP and tempuser) will give you a clue as to what user(s) besides the admin user are set up.) Also, on the command line, run `set APPDATA` to see if that environment variable is even set. (If things are set up correctly, it should be, since it's one of the ones that Windows sets by default and cannot be changed by the user.)